# Unable to build my first hello world Xamarin project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

When I start a new blank Xamarin project and click the play button with the android emulator highlighted, I get an error message saying:

[image]

Anyone know why this is happening?  I only just finished installing VS2019 community today and thought I would give Xamarin a test run.

Comment: Make sure that you had download the Android Support SDK . If the issue still appears, you can send the feedback. Open Visual Studio -> **Help** -> **Send  feedback** -> **report a problem** .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT, kind of got it working.  If I login using a domain admin account, everything works fine.  But if I login using a regular user account, I get the above issues.  I guess I need to somehow configure the whole environment to play nice with a regular user account.  Any ideas?

Comment: Right click your solution ->Properties->Configuration and check the **deploy** .

Comment: Had a look and that option is already checked.

Comment: Try to uninstall the android sdk and install it again .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT, done that and it still gives the same error message.  The problem is temporarily resolved if I do everything as domain admin (and even local administrator).  How do I get it to work with domain user (and standard local non-admin user)?

Comment: Open Visual Studio -> Help -> Send feedback -> report a problem .